# Reverse proxy heroku app to wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, heroku, reverse-proxy

I've managed to setup a reverse proxy of my heroku app with the following in config.ru

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
use Rack::ReverseProxy do  
   reverse_proxy /^\/blog(.*)$/, 'http://blog.domain.com$1', opts={:preserve_host => true}
end
run Appname::Application
```

This allows my heroku app to run at domain.com and have domain.com/blog appear as the URL while the wordpress site is being served blog.domain.com.  Great so far.

The wordpress site gets served properly when going to domain.com/blog, however when I go to any deeper page like an individual post wordpress throws an error.  I was using permalinks with the date and title in the URL of the form: domian.com/blog/2012/07/a-great-blog-post - Worpress now seems to not like this.  When I switched the links back to the form domain.com/blog/?p=4 the page gets served successfully.

It seems like it doesn't handle and sort of trailing slashes after the inial domain.com/blog properly.  What I find strange is domain.com/blog/wp-admin (and the entire WP admin app) works without any hiccups.

Can anyone see any glaring issues why the pages/post with multiple slashes '/' might be causing problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the error Apache seems to be throwing:
    Internal Server Error

    The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

    Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

    More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: I used rack reverse proxy and new relic is telling me that requests are spending a lot of time there, I am now trying https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack the bad thing is that is explained with unicorn while today puma is the recommended server.

Answer (score 2):

Well I found a solution, for whatever reason in the WP settings for the permalink, it didn't like any of the default options except for the form where it can retrieve the post by id. (http://www.domain.com/blog/?p=123)

For SEO purposes I wanted the title of the post to be in the URL. So I entered in the custom structure field:
    /index.php/%postname%/

It seems like it was requiring index.php for wordpress to handle the routing properly.